# Don't understand cplusplus.com example for istream::read

Tags: c++, istream

On cplusplus.com an example is given:

```
// read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {

  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length];

    std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);

    if (is)
      std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
    else
      std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
    is.close();

    // ...buffer contains the entire file...

    delete[] buffer;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why the last `if (is)` can determine if all characters have been read? It's the same if statement we're already in and the way I interpreted it (probably too simplistically and false at that) we only check if is exists, but wasn't this already established?

Comment: That's part of the semantics for `std::basic_istream` conversion to a boolean. See the table at the bottom of this page for details http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ifstream` has a conversion operator to `bool`, which returns whether or not `badbit` or `failbit` is set on the stream.

It is essentially shorthand for `if (!is.fail()) {/*...*/}`.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, 'is' is an object that has flag parameters in the form of booleans that can be switched on and off. When performing is.read() the flags are raised upon encountering problems within the stream, which can subsequently be checked for by performing if(is). So although the operation looks the same as a prior if(is) action, the state of 'is' could have been changed in the meantime?

Comment: @Omnia87 Yes, state could have changed, hence the extra check.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ifstream` defines `operator bool() const`, which implicitly converts the stream to a boolean.

From cplusplus.com on operator bool():

> Returns whether an error flag is set (either failbit or badbit).
>
> Notice that this function does not return the same as member good, but
>   the opposite of member fail.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/